# How do I find the model number on iPhone X or iPhone 8?

Tags: iphone

Since Apple removed the regulatory information from iPhone X and iPhone 8 that included the model number how I do I find the model number when a device won't power on?

Answer (score 3):

Since Apple removed the regulatory marks from the iPhone 8 and X the model number is now in [the sim tray slot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208200).

[image]